# How to measure upload bitrate using Java+Google Data API

Tags: java, youtube, google-data-api

I'm writing a Java client application which uses the Google Data API to upload things to youtube. I'm wondering how I would go about tracking the progress of an upload, using the Google Data API library I simply call service.insert to insert a new video, which blocks until it is complete.

Has anyone else come up with a solution to monitor the status of the upload and count the bytes as they are sent?

Thanks for any ideas

Link:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#Direct_Upload

Comment: How about implementing your own [MediaFileSource](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/media/MediaFileSource.html) with your own `InputStream` that watches how much data has been read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaSource writeTo() to include a counter of bytesRead:

```
     public static void writeTo(MediaSource source, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {

      InputStream sourceStream = source.getInputStream();
      BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sourceStream);
      long byteCounter = 0L; 

      try {
        byte [] buf = new byte[2048]; // Transfer in 2k chunks
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) >= 0) {
          // byte counter
          byteCounter += bytesRead;
          bos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead); 
        }
        bos.flush();
      } finally {
        bis.close();
      }
    }
  }
```